# Functions out of order when getting results from SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

When an existing SQL record exists I want to use it rather than adding another, but if it doesn't yet exist I want to add it. The issue I am having is that when my Node.js app's endpoint is called it's not executing in the correct order so the SQL lookup to find existing records is happening after I check it's length to see if I need to add a new record.

```
// it does this second
let existingGet = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE name = '" + productName + "'";
let existingItem = async () => {
    db.query(existingGet, function (err, rows, fields) {
        return rows;
    });
};

// it does this first
if (await existingItem().length > 0) {
    // Existing found, use existing
    itemId = existingItem.ID;
} else {
    // Item not found, create new
    var sql = "INSERT INTO Items (...) VALUES (...)";
    await db.query(sql, async function (err, result) {
        itemId = existingItem.affectedRows.ID;
    });
}
```

The desired outcome is that it does the first section before the second section because the second section needs the results of the first.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the outer brackets so that the `existingItem` will receive the result from the query

```js
// it does this second
let existingGet = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE name = '" + productName + "'";
//removed outer brackets
let existingItem = async () => 
    db.query(existingGet, function (err, rows, fields) {
        return rows;
    });


// it does this first
if (await existingItem().length > 0) {
    // Existing found, use existing
    itemId = existingItem.ID;
} else {
    // Item not found, create new
    var sql = "INSERT INTO Items (...) VALUES (...)";
    await db.query(sql, async function (err, result) {
        itemId = existingItem.affectedRows.ID;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it but it's still out of order. It checks the length before it gets the result

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a single db call using sql command

```
"INSERT INTO Items (...) VALUES (...)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Items WHERE name = ...)"
```

And use sql command parameters instead of concatenation to avoid sql injection.